# Able to run red5 oflademo & doing live streaming on my local,but not able to see the live streaming on other system in LAN

Tags: jwplayer, red5, live-streaming

I have installed red5 on my system & also installed oflademo. Able to do live streaming using adobe media live encoder in my local.Using jw player to play the video.The player is able to read rtmp url from 127.0.0.1 but when i hit the player url from other system in LAN.getting "Server not found rtmpt://ipaddress:80/oflademo".I have installed the player application in apache tomcat.

Comment: Are you pointing to the local router IP address?

Comment: ipaddress is mine's system ipaddress, one more thing i would like to tell is that ,when i have installed the red5, its asks for ipaddress & i have specified the 127.0.0.1 instead the ipaddress of my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the ipaddress instead 127.0.0.1 using my LAN ipaddress when installing the red5 and it is working now :). Thanks Ethan for your help